# Table join in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables I'm trying to join.

They share a primary key of orderNumber.

one table is named "order details" the other is "orders"

im trying to query productCode, quantityOrdered, priceEach, orderLineNumber from the "orderdetails" table.

From the "orders" table I need status and customer number.

The problem I'm running into is that I need to find 3 records with 3 specific orderNumbers.

I can query all the data I need, what I cant do is limit it to 3 specific order numbers... I'm stuck.

I posted a link to the ERD

any help would be great!!

Here is the code I tried.

```
SELECT orderNumber
     ,  productCode
     , quantityOrdered
     , priceEach
     , orderLineNumber
     , orders.status
     , customerNumber 
  from orderdetails 
  join orders 
    on orderdetails.orderNumber = orders.orderNumber 
 where orderNumber =  (10330,10338,10194);
```

I keep getting an orderNumber is ambiguous error.

Comment: Always qualify ALL column references, not just some of them.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm so new to SQL what do you mean by qualify all column references?

Comment: In the query above , status is an example of a properly qualified column

Comment: I see I see. So meaning orderDetails.productCode, orderdetails.priceEach...so on n so forth?

Answer (score 0):

1. If orderNumber - or any other column - is present in both tables, you should point to one of the tables in your SELECT statement:

   SELECT orders.orderNumber
2. Your WHERE statement should use IN keyword instead of orderNumber = (value1, value2):

   WHERE orders.orderNumber IN (10330,10338,10194)

Comment: I really appreciate your help, this is all so new to me, but I'm trying!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have to select from multiple options then use IN clause. Your query would be like this:

```
SELECT OD.ORDERNUMBER
    , OD.PRODUCTCODE
    , OD.QUANTITYORDERED
    , OD.PRICEEACH
    , OD.ORDERLINENUMBER
    , O.STATUS
    , O.CUSTOMERNUMBER 
FROM ORDERDETAILS OD
INNER JOIN ORDERS O ON OD.ORDERNUMBER = O.ORDERNUMBER  
WHERE OD.ORDERNUMBER IN (10330,10338,10194);
```